# Redirecting after clicking on the date datetimepicker rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

Redirecting after clicking on the date. 
I redirect only after selecting a date subsequent izmenneniya hands and remove the focus from the field. So I can not hide the field input in css. How to change the code after clicking on the date when sending the form?

html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'method_name' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag('datetimepicker12', nil, options = { :onchange => "this.form.submit()"}) %>
  <% end %>
```

js:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            inline: true,
            locale: 'ru',
            useCurrent: false
        });
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on you question? I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: lcguida, I want to by clicking on a calendar date occurred sending the selected date to the controller, and there is already redirected to another page (with the transfer of the selected date in parameters)

Comment: So maybe what you want is to submit this form in a ajax call, then get the response and based on that redirect your page to wherever you want to... no?